# How do I link the redirect uri to my localhost?

Tags: oauth2-playground

I'm trying to use localhost/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback as the redirect uri, but I keep getting `An error occured while connecting to the server: DNS lookup failed for URL: http://localhost/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The trick here is to set `http://localhost/users/auth/google_oauth2/callback` inside the API web interface as one of the redirect URLs. The client side is what gets redirected, so it has nothing to do with the network. Beginner mistake, so hopefully if you're reading this I saved you a headache :)